# Azure IoT Hub Framework 3.5

Tags: azure, .net-3.5, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

Are there any good tutorials or guides to using Azure IoT Hub via using the MQTT protocol from devices with framework 3.5? I found the M2MQTT client but it won't work with Azure IoT Hub.

Answer (score 2):

IoT Hub enables devices to communicate with the IoT Hub device endpoints using MQTT v3.1.1 protocol directly. You can take a look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support). In the document the tutorial is written in python, following code is a full sample for C# using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.

***C# Example:***

```
    private static string hostName = "<iothub-hosename>";
    private static int port = 8883;
    private static string deviceId = "<deviceid>";
    private static string userName = "";
    private static string password = "";
    private static string certBase64 = "<DigiCert Baltimore Root Certificate>";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            userName = $"{hostName}/{deviceId}/api-version=2016-11-14";
            password = $"SharedAccessSignature sr=<SAS Token>";

            byte[] certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(certBase64);
            X509Certificate caCert = new X509Certificate(certBytes);

            MqttClient client = new MqttClient(hostName, port, true, caCert, null , MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_0);
            client.ProtocolVersion = MqttProtocolVersion.Version_3_1_1;

            client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
            client.MqttMsgPublished += Client_MqttMsgPublished;
            client.ConnectionClosed += Client_ConnectionClosed;
            client.Connect(deviceId, userName, password);
            if(client.IsConnected)
            {
                //To receive messages from IoT Hub, a device should subscribe using devices/{device_id}/messages/devicebound/# as a Topic Filter. 
                client.Subscribe(new string[] { $"devices/{deviceId}/messages/devicebound/#" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE });

                //After making a successful connection, a device can send messages to IoT Hub using devices/{device_id}/messages/events/ or devices/{device_id}/messages/events/{property_bag} as a Topic Name. 
                client.Publish($"devices/{deviceid}/messages/events/", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{id=123}"), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE, false);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void Client_MqttMsgPublished(object sender, MqttMsgPublishedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mqtt Published Message-[MsgId:{0}]:{1}", e.MessageId, e.IsPublished ? "Success": "Failure");
    }

    private static void Client_ConnectionClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConnectionClosed");
    }

    private static void Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Message));
    }
```

In the code, you may need to copy the **DigiCert Baltimore Root Certificate** to `certBase64` from [certs.c](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/certs/certs.c) as base64 string(remove the lines `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`, and remove `\r\n\`).

**Update:**
[image]

**How to get SAS token?**

You can use [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer#sastoken) to generate SAS tokens,please see the device section of [Using IoT Hub security tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#use-sas-tokens-in-a-device-app).

Comment: it seems to me that the baltimore certificate does not work for IoT anymore. I post my actual code above, but I get CONNACK = 5

Comment: I think maybe you copied the incorrect certificate string. I have tested with above code, it works fine.Did you copy all the string in the `certs.c` file? `DigiCert Baltimore Root Certificate` is only the first part in the file.Please take a look at my update.

Comment: @elur, have you resolved the issue? If there is any question,feel free and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to **[Azure IoT Hub device SDK for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client/)**, and it working with **.NET Framework 3.5** ?  As per the GitHub [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp), it seems IoT Hub SDK for .NET supports only .NET Framework 4.5.1 and above only.

Alternatively, Simply using [Azure IoT Hub Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/) - then you can make HTTP requests from your legacy .NET Framework 3.5 code

Comment: Hi,@NiTRiX-Reloaded ,from the github(https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp), it seems that IoT Hub SDK for .NET supports only .NET Framework 4.5.1 and above only.